# Dice probability normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

You roll a dice 1000 times. Calculate the probability you roll a six between 150 and 200 times.
I understand how you calculate this with the binomial distribution:
$$ = Binomialcdf(1000, 1/6, 200) - Binomialcdf(1000, 1/6, 149) = 0.9975-0.0710=0.9265 $$

How do you do this with the normal distribution?
The answer should be 92.53%.
Problem is when I use Normalcdf(200) - Normalcdf(150) I get 0.9190
What am I doing wrong?

My second question:
If you roll exactly 200 times a six, what is the probability there will be less than 150 times a five?
Again I understand how I could calculate it with the binomial distribution, but not with the normal distribution...
Answer should be 20.04%

Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer based on the normal distribution is an approximation justified by central limit theorem (CLT). You need to properly normalize (i.e., standardize) you sum to use the CLT.

Comment: I would cross my fingers and use the continuity correction, so find the probability a suitable normal is $\le 200.5$ minus the probability the normal is $\le 149.5$. That may give a better approximation.

Comment: Excellent suggestion! I didn't use the continuity correction for my first question. It seems that gives me the correct value. Thanks! On to the second one...